# Android resize text edit control

Tags: android, android-layout, drawing, android-edittext

I've got a text edit, and I'm trying to re-size it when the screen resizes (because of the keyboard)

```
@Override
    protected void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
        super.onSizeChanged(w,h,oldw,oldh);
        if(m_editScreen != null){
            LayoutParams par = (LayoutParams) m_editScreen.getLayoutParams();
            par.height = h - 30;
            m_editScreen.setLayoutParams(par);          
        }
    }
```

When tap into the text area the box resizes down to the right height.. (30 is the top offset)
When I close the keyboard, the text box stays small.  Even though the h value is back to the original.

Is there something I'm missing?   I really didn't expect positioning controls would be so hard.

Comment: Are you sure the size changes when the keyboard appears? I thought it would be called only once, between ònCreate` and `onSDraw`. Is this method called when you re-open the keyboard?

Comment: Yeah.. it does.. you have to put a setting in your manifest... I have a break point on the par.height =... line, h gets changed each time.  The method is called on close and open of keyboard.

Comment: It's probably safer to call `invalidate()` on `m_editScreen`, then

Comment: Yeah.. I tried that too.. this is a right pain in the butt.   The scroll trucksize didn't change when the keyboard went away, which signals to me it's not a paint.  When I scroll it doesn't repaint.